# Catchall with Exim and Virtual Host

Tags: email, exim, pipe

I tried following the tutorial at: http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP.html to pipe incoming mail to a PHP script for a virtual host with Exim.  I can't seem to get it working.  Any ideas?

Here's my exim.conf setup:

http://www.ysend.com/exim.txt

I have created the directory:

/etc/exim/vhosts

And created a file: ysend.com in it, with:

> catch-all: |php -q /home/ysend/public_html/handler.php

I also tried:

> *: |php -q /home/ysend/public_html/handler.php

As well as:

> catch-all: my.email.address@site.com

and

> *: my.email.address@site.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a

exim -bt someaddress@site.com

Exim is quite talky about what it is doing.

You may add the following line to your exim.conf main section

trusted_users = yourapacheuser

(apacheuser may be www-data on debian/ubuntu, httpd on redhat/fedora)

and most importantly: move your vhost_alias from routers to directors. routers are for mails sent offsite, directors on how to handle local mails.

Comment: For the command:

[root@server ~]# exim -bt test@ysend.com
Zhay07@gmail.com
    <-- test@ysend.com
  router = dnslookup, transport = remote_smtp
  host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com      [209.85.217.71]  MX=5
  host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.210.21]  MX=10
  host alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.201.114] MX=20
  host alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.133.114] MX=30
  host alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.218.27]  MX=40

And trusted_users = apache is already there :)

Where is the directors section?  Do I have to create it?

Comment: When I change the /etc/exim/vhosts/ysend.com file so that it says:
catch-all: |php -q /home/ysend/public_html/handler.php
and I run the exim -bt test@ysend.com command, it says: Unrouteable address

Comment: I switched it from catchall to *, and now I get:

[root@server ~]# exim -bt lol@ysend.com
lol@ysend.com -> |php -q /home/ysend/public_html/handler.php
  transport = address_pipe